# Проблема с доступом в джой...(C++)|Цепное включение заголовочных файлов|С++

Tags: c++, qt, объявление

Здравствуйте, форумчане! Описываю ситуацию: класс AddressBookParser не видит класс TextEdit. Оба являются производными, от соответствующих классов библиотеки QT. * Ошибки *:

*'TextEdit' does not name a type
     TextEdit* edit;*

**И**

*no matching function for call to 'AddressBookParser::AddressBookParser(TextEdit*, QString)'
         AddressBookParser* parcer = new AddressBookParser(this,edit->text());*

**Т.е везде, где обращаюсь или создаю объект типа TextEdit**

Перепробовал, все что знаю, начиная от прототипа TextEdit перед объявлением AddressBookParcer(где-то читал, что если файлы подключают друг друга по списку 1->2->3 , то 3 может узнать 2й класс, хз как это называется), заканчивая добавлением строго правильных конструкторов типа TextEdit(QWidget*p):QTextEdit(p){}.

**Почему же компилятор говорит, что TextEdit'а нету? И как это исправить?**
Взываю к вашей мудрости, СПАСИБО! P.S программа просматривает XML документ, и выводит контакт по номеру("number="i"), который вводится в QLineEdit и должна вывести содержимое этого контакта в TextEdit, и да, тут используется SAX(См. М.Шлее Программирование в Qt5.3, глава 40)

```
//addressbookparcer.h
#ifndef ADDRESSBOOKPARSER_H
#define ADDRESSBOOKPARSER_H

#include <QXmlDefaultHandler>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QException>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "textedit.h"


class AddressBookParser : public QXmlDefaultHandler
{
private:
    TextEdit* edit;
    QString _text; // данные
    int number;
    bool finded;
public:
    AddressBookParser(TextEdit* e, QString num)
    {
        number = num.toInt();
        edit = e;
        finded = false;
    }
    //переопределенные методы, расположены в порядке вызова
    virtual bool startElement(const QString &namespaceURI,
                     const QString &localName,
                     const QString &qName,
                     const QXmlAttributes &atts) //атрибуты документа
    {
        finded = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < atts.count(); i++){
            if(atts.value(i) == QString::number(number)) {
                 edit->setText(edit->toPlainText() + "\nAttribute: " + atts.value(i));
                 finded = true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool characters(const QString& text)
    {
        _text = text;
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool endElement(const QString&, const QString&, const QString& str)
    {
        if(str != "contact" && str != "addressbook" && finded) { //не обрабатываем /contact, /addressbook
            edit->setText(edit->toPlainText() + "\nTag name: " + str + "\t Text: " + _text);
        }
        return true;
    }

    virtual bool fatalError(const QXmlParseException& ex) //обработка исключительных ситуаций
    {
        qDebug() << "Line: " << ex.lineNumber() << "\t Column: " << ex.columnNumber() << "\t Message: " << ex.message();
        return false;
    }
};
#endif // ADDRESSBOOKPARSER_H

//textedit.h
#ifndef TEXTEDIT_H
#define TEXTEDIT_H
#include "addressbookparser.h"

class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLineEdit* edit;
public:
    TextEdit(QLineEdit* edit){
        this->edit = edit;
    }
public slots:
    void parcerSlot(bool)
    {
        bool f;
        edit->text().toInt(&f);
        if(!f)
            return;
        AddressBookParser* parcer = new AddressBookParser(this,edit->text());
        QFile* file = new QFile("addressbook.xml");

        QXmlInputSource source(file); //объект источника для парсинга документа
        QXmlSimpleReader reader; //ридер документа

        reader.setContentHandler(parcer); //устанавливаем обработчик
        reader.parse(source); //запуск парсинга
    }
};

#endif // TEXTEDIT_H

//main.cpp
#include "textedit.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try{
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QWidget wgt;
        wgt.resize(600,100);

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(&wgt);

        QLineEdit* line = new QLineEdit;
        TextEdit* edit = new TextEdit(line);
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("обработать");

        layout->addWidget(line);
        layout->addWidget(edit);
        layout->addWidget(button);
        wgt.show();

        QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), edit, SLOT(parcerSlot(bool)));

        return app.exec();
    }
    catch(QException& ex) //обработка ошибок
    {
        QMessageBox M;
        M.setText(QString(ex.what()));
        M.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Заголовок  textedit.h включает в себя заголовок с определением AddressBookParser?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, да, но я пробовал убирать и делать другие включения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас заголовок `textedit.h` включает в себя заголовок `addressbookparser.h`

```
//textedit.h
#ifndef TEXTEDIT_H
#define TEXTEDIT_H
#include "addressbookparser.h"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому этот включенный первым заголовок не видит объявление `TextEdit`, так как в результате объявление класса `AddressBookParser` идет перед объявлением класса 
`TextEdit`.

Вам следует сначала объявить классы, а затем определять вне класса его функции. А в заголовках просто включить предварительные объявления типа

```
class AddressBookParser;
```

Вот как будет выглядеть, например, заголовок `textedit.h`

```
// textedit.h
#ifndef TEXTEDIT_H
#define TEXTEDIT_H

class AddressBookParser;
```

// Даже можно убрать это объявление, если нет на него ссылки в объявлении класса TextEdit

```
class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLineEdit* edit;
public:
    TextEdit(QLineEdit* edit){
        this->edit = edit;
    }
public slots:
    void parcerSlot(bool);
};

#endif // TEXTEDIT_H
```

А саму функцию определите в отдельном файле, включив эти два заголовка.

Comment: Так что вы предлагаете? Я вроде пробовал сделать так : main.cpp (textedit.h), textedit.h(addressbookparcer.h), addressbook.h(ничего, но перед объяалением добавил class TextEdit)

Comment: @Xambey Ч написал, что я предлагаю.

Comment: Хорошо, щас попробую еще разок

Comment: Спасибо, помогло